# mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in

Tags: php, mysqli

Already looked at the other answers but couldn't fix it. Monday i've got school exams and they want us to build a basic CMS (add, edit, delete pages, resized images). My programming knowledge is beginner and I don't know much about OOP (PDO), design patterns, best practices and like that kind of things.

As I checked my query in phpMyAdmin it looks fine. In the header include there is the connection included.

```
<?php
    include('inc/header.php');
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
        $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
        $password_secure = md5($password);

        if($username == "") {
            $error++;
            $_SESSION["loginerror"] = true;
            header("location: loginerror.php");
            exit;
        }

        if($password == "") {
            $error++;
            $_SESSION["loginerror"] = true;
            header("location: loginerror.php");
            exit;
        }

        if($username != "" && $password != "") {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '".$username."' 
            AND password = '".$password_secure."'";
        }

        if(mysqli_num_rows($query == 1)) {
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
            $_SESSION['username'] = $row["username"];
            $_SESSION['firstname'] = $row["firstname"];
            $_SESSION['lastname'] = $row["lastname"];
            $_SESSION['login'] = true;
            header("location: user.php");
            exit;
        }

    } else {
        header("location: index.php");
        exit;
    }
?>
```

Is it also smart to check the POST request with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'` instead of a isset() and escape SQL with `mysql_real_escape_string` in the query?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

Comment: Regardless of what `$query` is, the parentheses in the `if` condition `mysqli_num_rows($query == 1)` are most definitely misplaced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to execute the query

```
$query = mysqli_query($sql);

$rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($query);
```

and then

```
if($rowcount == 1){
 // do ur stuff
}
```

Comment: Oh stupid from me, forgotted to put the $query variable again in before submitting the answer. Sorry, haha. Error is gone but I'm still not redirected to user.php. Thanks for helping.